# How to use LIMIT clause with postgres and Hibernate/Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-rest

I have this native query that won't work in my DAO

```
@Query(
            nativeQuery = true,
            value = "DELETE FROM products_in_carts WHERE cart_id =?1 AND product_name = ?2 LIMIT= 1"
    )
    void removeProduct(long id, String productName);
```

Which returns: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "LIMIT"`

I tried with `OFFSET` as suggested in some other questions but won't work either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because, as i understand the documentation correctly, postgres does not support using `LIMIT` in `delete` statement. Therefore you can try using a workaround to achieve your requirement. For example getting the rows to delete by using a subquery inside the delete statement. As I do not know your table design I am using the `CTID` here from postgres to identify the row to delete.

Taken from the documentation (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/ddl-system-columns.html)

> ctid
> The physical location of the row version within its table. Note that although the ctid can be used to locate the row version very quickly, a row's ctid will change each time it is updated or moved by VACUUM FULL. Therefore ctid is useless as a long-term row identifier. The OID, or even better a user-defined serial number, should be used to identify logical rows.

For example (not tested):

```
@Query(
        nativeQuery = true,
        value = "DELETE FROM products_in_carts WHERE ctid in (select ctid from product cart_id =?1 AND product_name = ?2 LIMIT= 1)"
)
void removeProduct(long id, String productName);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Postgres DELETE statement doesn't support LIMIT.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-delete.html

Make use of where in order to delete the desired rows.